# I found $E(Σ_{j=0}^{k-1}η_j-Σ_{j=0}^{k-1}E(η_j|G_j))^2=Σ_{j=0}^{k-1}(E(η_j)^2-E(E(η_j|G_j)^2)$ in a book with faulty assumptions on the objects

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, conditional-expectation

In [Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/probability-theory-and-stochastic-processes/stochastic-equations-infinite-dimensions) (Second Edition) on page 109, the authors state the following:

> If $\eta_0,\ldots,\eta_{k-1}$ are random variables with finite second moments and $\mathcal G_0,\ldots,\mathcal G_{k-1}$ an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-fields such that $\eta_i$ are measurable with respect to $\mathcal G_j$, $0\le j\le k-1$, then $$\mathbb E\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\eta_j-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\mathbb E\left(\eta_j\mid\mathcal G_j\right)\right)^2=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\mathbb E(\eta_j)^2-\mathbb E(\mathbb E\left(\eta_j\mid\mathcal G_j\right)^2\right)\;.\tag 1$$

I've taken the statement literally; preserving any grammatical, logical and notational error (you can find at least one error of each category).

> It's an odd question, but I need to ask it: How can we phrase the statement correctly?

At a first glance, I thought they would mean the following: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space, $I:=\left\{0,\ldots,k-1\right\}$, $(\mathcal G_i)_{i\in I}$ be a filtration of $\mathcal A$ and $(\eta_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq\mathcal L^2(\operatorname P)$ be $\mathcal F$-adapted. Then it holds $(1)$ (with the parenthesis mismatch being corrected). However, that would be a trivial statement, cause $\operatorname E\left[\eta_i\mid\mathcal G_i\right]$ would be equal to $\eta_i$ and hence both sides of $(1)$ would be $0$.

So, what do they mean?

Comment: Suggestion: If a square-integrable process $(\eta_j)_{j\geqslant1}$ is adapted to a filtration $(\mathcal G_j)_{j\geqslant0}$ then $$\mathbb E\left(\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}\eta_j-\mathbb E\left(\eta_j\mid\mathcal G_{j-1}\right)\right)^2\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\mathbb E\left(\eta_j^2\right)-\mathbb E\left(\mathbb E\left(\eta_j\mid\mathcal G_{j-1}\right)^2\right)$$

Comment: @Did Is it important that the sums are finite? Or do they converge for $k\to\infty$?

Comment: This obviously depends on $(\eta_j)$.

Comment: How do you deal with the $$\operatorname E\left[\eta_i\operatorname E\left[\eta_i\mid\mathcal G_{i-1}\right]\right]$$ on the left-hand side of your equation?

Comment: Unsurprisingly, I use the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are square-integrable and $Y$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable then $$E(XY)=E(E(XY\mid \mathcal G))=E(E(X\mid \mathcal G)Y).$$

Comment: @Did I don't see that you use this fact. Here $X=Y=\eta_i$ and $\mathcal G=\mathcal G_{i-1}$, but $Y$ is not $\mathcal G$-measurable.

Comment: You simply have to refrain from jumping instantly to the obvious and useless choice $X=Y=\eta_j$. In other words, if you decide all by yourself that the hint does not work, well... so be it.

Comment: @Did If $k=1$, then the difference of the left-hand and right-hand side of your equation is $$2\operatorname E\left[\eta_1\operatorname E\left[\eta_1\mid\mathcal G_0\right]\right]\;.\tag 1$$ Since you say that your equation *is* an equation, $(1)$ should be $0$ and I don't think that this is the case.

Comment: No, you seem to meet some sign problems in basic algebraic manipulations... but looking at the case $k=1$ is definitely a good idea. Courage!

Comment: @Did I'm sorry, I've misread your equation. Now it's obvious. You've used your statement with $X=\eta_i$, $Y=\operatorname E\left[\eta_i\mid\mathcal G_{i-1}\right]$ and $\mathcal G=\mathcal G_{i-1}$ to obtain that $$\operatorname E\left[\eta_i\operatorname E\left[\eta_i\mid\mathcal G_{i-1}\right]\right]=\operatorname E\left[\operatorname E\left[\eta_i\mid\mathcal G_{i-1}\right]^2\right]\;.$$ Thank you very much for your help.